# How to format a data having float+string like 1.2k to float (1200) in python?

Tags: python, string

Data file looks like this:
350 1.06k
351 1.10k
352 1.15k

Required output:
350 1060
351 1100
352 1150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
data = ['350 1.06k', '351 1.10k', '352 1.15k']

def covert_string(var):
        return float(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+?.?', var)).replace(' ',''))*1000

for value in data:
        print covert_string(value)

## -- End pasted text --
3501060.0
3511100.0
3521150.0
```

I hope this solution works for you

Comment: This works. But problem is I have an array of length 1000 or more, so putting apostrophe to each and every value( i.e formatting 1.2k to '1.2k') is a problem! Please help in this regard!

Comment: use `map(str, data)` it will convert all the list element to `str`

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
data = ['350 1.06k', '351 1.10k', '352 1.15k']

def convert(item):
    item = item.split()
    item[1] = str(float(item[1][:-1]) * 1000)[:-2]
    return ' '.join(item)

res = [convert(i) for i in data]
print(res)
```