# How would I change a number such as 1.2k into its equivalent of 1200 in python

Tags: python

This is going to be part of a calculator, so i don't have just the number, but the expression of say: `1k + 2*3**(4m^5) / (6k + -7)`
Currently I have:

```
expr = expr.replace('k','000')
expr = expr.replace('K','000')
expr = expr.replace('m','000000')
expr = expr.replace('M','000000')
```

This doesn't work with decimals such as 1.2k - it returns 1.2000
I have got this to check for decimal points, and get the index of it, but am unsure what needs to be done next:

```
if '.' in expr:
    result = expr.find('.')
```

EDIT: Thanks to @GodWin for his solution of replacing k with e3 etc
My finished code is this:

```
import discord
import ast
import operator as op

operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
             ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.Pow: op.pow, ast.BitXor: op.xor,
             ast.USub: op.neg}

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

def eval_expr(expr):
    try:
        expr = expr.replace('x','*')
        expr = expr.replace('X','*')
        expr = expr.replace('k','e3')
        expr = expr.replace('K','e3')
        expr = expr.replace('m','e6')
        expr = expr.replace('M','e6')
        return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)
    except:
        return
def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num): # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp): # <left> <operator> <right>
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp): # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand))
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
       return

    answer = eval_expr(message.content)
    if answer != None: await message.channel.send(f'{message.content} = {answer}')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Using a regular expression (module "re") you can find the number and the factor letter and then replace e. g. "6k" by "(6*1000)". The parentheses ensure the right priority of the multiplication.

Comment: Is your intention to keep things in string form, or do you only care about converting to numbers to perform the calculation?

Comment: If it's normal string and you are interested to directly calculate it with `eval` replace `k` with `e3` and `m` with `e6` which means `10^3` and `10^6` and eval will calculate it. Decimal won't have any issue with this.

Comment: The solution you're looking for could be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335660/how-to-format-a-data-having-floatstring-like-1-2k-to-float-1200-in-python).  Edit: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307730/converting-a-string-number-such-as-31-1-m-to-a-numeric-float) seems more practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the mistake:
So the k is replaced by 3 zeros. if it is 2k, it will be 2000
If it is 1.2k, it will be 1.2000
so try something like this:

```
x = "1.2k"
y=x.replace("k", "")
y=float(y)*1000

print(y)
```

Do the same for millions(m) and billions(b)

Answer (score 0):

You could throw regex at this:

```
import re     
yournumber= '1.2k'    
numdict = {'k':1000,'m':1000000,'b':1000000000}    
print(float(re.findall(r'[0-9.]*', yournumber)[0]) * numdict[re.findall(r'k|m|b', yournumber)[0]])
```

Or you could check that the number string is formatted in an expected way and then pick out and multiply:

```
import re     
yournumber= '1.2k'    
numdict = {'k':1000,'m':1000000,'b':1000000000}    
if re.match(rf"[0-9.]*[%s]$"%''.join(numdict.keys()), yournumber):
    print(float(re.findall(r'[0-9.]*', yournumber)[0]) * numdict[yournumber[-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx with `re.sub` can be really helpful here. To convert a whole fomula like `1.2k + 2*3**(4m^5) / (6k + -7)` you can use the code below:

```
import re


def letter_to_number_converter(match):
    """
    :param match: Matches a number ending with a letter from the keys in multipliers.
    :return: Integer, converted to String, that equals the matched number multiplied by the value against the matched letter.
    """
    multipliers = {
        'k': 1000,
        'm': 1000000,
    }

    number_with_letter = match.group()
    number = float(number_with_letter[:-1])
    letter = number_with_letter[-1]

    if letter.lower() in multipliers:
        number_with_digits_only = int(number * multipliers[letter.lower()])

        # The re.sub expects a return type of String.
        return str(number_with_digits_only)

    # Just in case there is no match against the multipliers' dictionary.
    return number_with_letter


expr = "1.2k + 2*3**(4m^5) / (6k + -7)"

# Use a function (letter_to_number_converter) to fetch the match from the regular expression in re.sub.
# The re.IGNORECASE flag is used to match both k and K and so on.
print(re.sub(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[km]", letter_to_number_converter, expr, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```